# Audio Player as Custom Field in Custom Object

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, custom-field

I wonder if it is possible at all to create/use audio player as a custom field and add it to the custom object.

My target is to have a "Phonecall" custom object and store call data in that object such as:

- Call ID
- Call Date & Time
- Service Number
- URL To call Recording

I also want to be able to play that call recording using some audio player.

Something like in the screenshot attached.

[image]

Would the audio player have to be a field belonging to that object? Or a visualforce page ? I am a bit lost I don't know how to "merge" the player with the object.

Comment: from where you are getting the details like Call ID, Call Date & Time, Service Number and URL?

Comment: @SarojBera from third-party telephony provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intriguing use-case you have here. I don't believe there would be any way to render in something as complex as an audio player from a formula field (or at least, no way that would be relatively simple/lightweight **and** secure).
My suggestion would be to make a Visualforce page embedded on the page layout, and have it display the audio player using [apex:flash](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_flash.htm) or maybe raw JavaScript depending on what kind of audio player you intend to use.

**edit:** Apparently, [HTML5 directly supports audio](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp) as long as your clients are using a browser modern enough for HTML5

Comment: I have managed to render audio player using HTML5. How do I link my "Phonecall" custom object to visualforce page with media player?

Comment: Make your VF page use  `standardController="Phonecall__c"` then in the audio source tag, set the `src` attribute to something like `src="{!Phonecall__c.Recording_URL__c}"`.